# How to save active class to localstorage

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, local-storage

How to save active color to localstorage and keep selected, when reloading page? A same case on stackoverflow was tried but did not work for me. i don't understand,  not expert in JavaScript. Hoping you<sub>,</sub> guys<sub>,</sub> will help me!

html

```html
    <div class="toolbar_item">
                <p class="block mb-4 text-slate-500 text-sm">Choose shirt color</p>
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                    <div id="1" class="color color-white active-color"></div>
                    <div id="2" class="color color-slate"></div>
                    <div id="3" class="color color-red"></div>
                    <div id="4" class="color color-teal"></div>
                    <div id="5" class="color color-blue"></div>
                    <div id="6" class="color color-yellow"></div>
                    <div id="7" class="color color-orange"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```js
    const COLOR_BTNS = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
    COLOR_BTNS.forEach((color) => {
    color.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let colorNameClass = color.className;
        if (!color.classList.contains("active-color")) {
            let colorName = colorNameClass.slice(
                colorNameClass.indexOf("-") + 1,
                colorNameClass.length
            );
            resetActiveBtn();
            color.classList.add("active-color");
            console.log(colorName);
            setNewColor(colorName);
        }
    });
    });

    // Reset Active Color
    function resetActiveBtn() {
    COLOR_BTNS.forEach((color) => {
        color.classList.remove("active-color");
    });
    }

    // Set New Color
    function setNewColor(color) {
    document.querySelector("#placeholder_depan").src =
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/blabla/shirt-color/depan-" + color + ".png";
    document.querySelector("#placeholder_belakang").src =
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/blabla/shirt-color/belakang-" +
        color +
        ".png";

    document.getElementById("img").src =
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/blabla/shirt-color/depan-" + color + ".png";

    document.getElementById("img1").src =
        "https://ik.imagekit.io/blabla/shirt-color/belakang-" +
        color +
        ".png";
    }
```

Comment: [localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You have to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) `setItem` and `getItem` in order to store something in localstorage and retrieve it on reload. I don't see you using it anywhere, so that's probably your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save to the storage:

```
if('localStorage' in this){ // this is the window, you should check it...
   try{
       localStorage.setItem('activeColorC',smth)
       //where smth (a String !) was an
       //element, color, image, class, id etc.
       } catch {}
   }
```

Retrieving it:

```
// when page re-loaded…
const activeFromStorage=localStorage.getItem('activeColorC');
document.body.setAttribute('onDOMContentLoaded',` // some code to
//make the remembered element BY A CATEGORY
//active again `);
```

<sub>Some data may be easy to save through caching, like in Audio (`new Audio( )`)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) interface. It's very intuitive and easy to use.

Just as an example, to save a variable as an active color:

```
localStorage.setItem('activeColor', 'Red');
```

Then, to recover:

```
localStorage.getItem('activeColor');
```